# More specific duplicated answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Every once in a while I see an answer that is good, and hits the core, but misses a lot of important notes or details. When I see these, I can think of three things I can do to improve the answer:

1. Leave a comment suggesting possible updates to the answer
2. Edit the answer
3. Leave my own answer.

But all of those have some major pitfalls.

1. If I just leave comments, there is no guarantee the answer will be updated and then people might not look at the comments.
2. I am happy to edit the answer, but If I edit an answer to improve its effectiveness I feel like I get cheated since I do not partake of any of the gained rep. It all goes to the Original poster, even if my edit made it correct.
3. If I was a jerk I would always leave my own "better" answer since I get to take all the rep! However, I feel that is unfair. I could give credit to the original poster, but they still dont get any rep. Normally, if the original poster has a ton of rep, I don't really worry about it, but when they have less rep than me, I feel bad about "stealing" their rep.

This question is twofold:

Perhaps there could be a feature where you can "give credit" to someone when you post your answer. Kindof like tagging someone in your original post, and then split the proceeds. This is especially useful in bounties. I recently posted a bounty question, and some of the answers where so similar I almost didn't know who to give the bounty too.

Second, as a discussion, what are some things you do in these situations?

Please note: This situation occurs BEFORE an answer is chosen. If an answer is already chosen, I just leave it since it was obviously enough information.

Answer (score 4):

There is never one right answer that applies in every case, but in 90% of cases based on what you have laid out, options (1) and (3) are usually the best alternatives.

> If I just leave comments, there is no guarantee the answer will be updated and then people might not look at the comments.

That's correct, people might not look at the comment and it is also true that the author may not edit the answer to include your suggestion.  The answer's author might not have read the comment or, more likely, read your comment and decided that it is not nearly as important as you think it is to include.

> I am happy to edit the answer, but If I edit an answer to improve its effectiveness I feel like I get cheated since I do not partake of any of the gained rep. It all goes to the Original poster, even if my edit made it correct.

This is where my missing 10% comes from my opening sentence.  If you are changing the answer that much that you will feel "cheated" by not earning any rep, then you are changing the answer too much, and it should not be an edit, but rather a new answer.

> If I was a jerk I would always leave my own "better" answer since I get to take all the rep! However, I feel that is unfair. I could give credit to the original poster, but they still dont get any rep. Normally, if the original poster has a ton of rep, I don't really worry about it, but when they have less rep than me, I feel bad about "stealing" their rep.

Don't feel like a jerk.  If you think you can expand on an answer to provide a better and/or more complete answer, then do it.  If the additional information you want to provide is really that much more substantial that you think that is would earn that much more rep than an existing answer, then you deserve that rep that comes from the change.  Just remember that if you are building off an existing answer, don't forget to attribute the original author.

> Please note: This situation occurs BEFORE an answer is chosen. If an answer is already chosen, I just leave it since it was obviously enough information.

Whether the answer is accepted or not shouldn't matter at all.  Your answer is not for the author of the question, it is for everyone.  If you think you can contribute to a question, then contribute.  Answers are supposed to be for everyone, so questions from 3 years ago that have accepted answers may still get new answers because there are new ways to accomplish the task.